# SSRS Reports drop down filtering data

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have an SSRS report that contains a drop down list with a rather large data set. I can select several items in the drop-down menu, but I can't filter out any specific value I want to find... Is it possible to add a text box that can be used to filter the data in the drop-down menu? or is there any other control that supports filtering + selecting values? A report is generated based on the selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a text parameter with no available or default values.

Add the new parameter, call it say `pSearchText`.

Then in the dataset query that populates the available values in your drop down parameter just change it to something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE(@pSearchText)
```

Be aware that you will not be able to search, add a couple of selections and then search for something different as the available values list will change. e.g. you cannot search for `land`, choose England and Finland then search for `ger` and choose Germany as the England and Finland selections will be lost.

If you need to search for multiple values then let me know and I'll post a modified answer.